# Wingpanel Setting to Hide When Windows are Maximized

Tags: settings, wingpanel

I think Wingpanel having the ability to dodge maximized, or to integrate maximized window borders the way Unity used to. Plank has done this for years, as does Xfce, KDE, etc. It doesn't seem like a complex feature and many users would benefit. One reason is the irritation of moving my cursor to the upper corner of the screen and finding that I passed up the X button. Cursor gymnastics! That and having a window border beneath a panel is cosmetically unpleasing. Bringing back Wingpanel Slim would be a welcoming option as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### Wingpanel Autohide Script by [Yunn](https://launchpad.net/~yunnxx/+archive/ubuntu/elementary) (works in elementary OS Juno)

**To allow installing the script from PPA:**

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

**To install the script:**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary

sudo apt update

sudo apt install elementary-wingautohide
```

**To autostart the script:**
go to `System Settings > Applications > Startup`, click `Add Autostart App...` button in the bottom-left corner and paste this command into the `Type in a custom command` field:

```
sh /usr/bin/wingautohide.sh
```

**To uninstall the script:**

```
sudo apt purge elementary-wingautohide
```

Comment: PPAs can't be added to Elementary.

Comment: To enable PPAs, execute this command in Terminal: `sudo apt install software-properties-common`.

Answer (score 0):

Something about it here. Translator needed.

https://entornosgnulinux.com/2019/01/20/autohide-en-wingpanel-para-elementary-os-juno/

Comment: That's the same thing as the option above.